# jQuery not running on first load after clearing the cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This makes no sense to me as the title says my jQuery isn't running on first load after clearing the cache, but if I refresh the page again this time not clearing the cache it works. I'm working on a WordPress site and I have included my js in the functions file heres all the code for my js.

```
function enqueue_my_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'alliance_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('slick_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/slick/slick.min.js');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts');

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    /*positioning the footer*/
    var nav_cont = jQuery("#hd_ft_cont").height();
    var header = jQuery("#main_nav").height();
    var footer = jQuery("#footer").height();

    var position = nav_cont - header - footer;
    jQuery("#footer").css("top", position);

    /*setting padding on content equal to width of the nav to avoid overlay*/
    var nav_width = jQuery("#hd_ft_cont").outerWidth();
    jQuery(".page_cont_wrapper, .head").css("paddingLeft", nav_width);

    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        var nav_width = $("#hd_ft_cont").outerWidth();
        jQuery(".page_cont_wrapper, .head").css("paddingLeft", nav_width);
    });

    jQuery(".carousel").css("paddingLeft", nav_width);

    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        var nav_width = jQuery("#hd_ft_cont").outerWidth();
        jQuery(".carousel").css("paddingLeft", nav_width);
    });
});
```

Comment: I've noticed that if I include my js in the head using the script tag it works. Whats going wrong in my functions file?

Comment: You are mixing Javascript in your PHP file. Javascript is the output of PHP scripts. You either enqueue the js as a separate script (recommended) or print the javascript on the HTML page directly.

Comment: Could you show me what you are talking about as I don't understand

Comment: Right now your JavaScript is in your PHP file, not in your HTML output. Like you know you said when you put the code in HTML header, it works. Your javascript right now is in your PHP file. You can put this javascript into a file and enqueue it like how you are enqueuing the other two scripts at the beginning of  your code snippet.